# no sudo permissions to /etc/hostname

Tags: command-line, files, sudo, permissions

When I try to edit my `/etc/hostname` file, using `sudo nano /etc/hostname` (or any other editor) I get the following:

```
Error writing /etc/hostname: Permission denied
```

I then tried:

```
sudo chmod u+w ./hostname
```

And got the error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of `./hostname': Operation not permitted
```

I get the same error trying to add write permissions to any use or group.

This is what `ls` shows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22 2012-06-18 12:25 /etc/hostname
```

Any idea why and what can I do about it?

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: can you plz " cat /etc/hosts ? cat /etc/hostname ? "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your `/etc/hostname` file is 'immutable', by way of having the immutable filesystem attribute. You can check with [`lsattr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lsattr.1.html), and should see something like this:

```
[jk@pecola ~]$ lsattr /etc/hostname
-------------e- /etc/hostname
```

if there's an `i` in there, your file is immutable. You can change this with:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/hostname
```

Then you should be able to edit it.

For more information about filesystem attributes, and the attributes that are available, see [the manpage for `chattr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lsattr.1.html):

```
man chattr
```

[This article](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/focus-linux-filesystem-security-ext2-extended-attributes) is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

This could be greatly frowned upon, but the following works for me:

`$ sudoedit /etc/hostname`

> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
>   Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
>
> ```
> #1) Respect the privacy of others.
> #2) Think before you type.
> #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
> ```

Comment: Why would this be frowned upon? Using `sudoedit` is one of the good, recommended ways to edit system files owned by root. (On the other hand, given that sudo cannot `chmod` the file and a `nano` run by `sudo` cannot change it, it's **very** unlikely that this approach will *work* for this problem. But it's not frowned upon.)